# What does happen under the hood in a Git checkout?

Tags: git, git-checkout, internals

I've noticed that if I'm on master and then I check out a particularly old branch (let's say...a month or two old), it takes about 10 seconds. Once I've checked it out, if I switch from this branch back to master, or from master back to this branch, the checkout speed is cut down to about 1 second.

I understand that the pointers are changing (i.e., the HEAD file which points to the ref, which then points to all the associated objects) when you do a git checkout. But what else is happening under the hood on a git checkout? And why does the checkout process between two branches speed up after you've done it once?

Are we perhaps unpacking objects or something along those lines? I'd imagine that if we check out a branch, we'd want all associated content in loose object form as it seems more readily available and easy to edit versus the deltas that git gc eventually packs them into.

Thanks!

Comment: I would guess what you see is likely to simply be file system cache being warm the second time.

Answer (score 4):

Except updating the head file and the reflog file (which takes no time), the only thing done is finding compressed objects (and sometimes packed), uncompress them and populate the working directory. 
I think that the difference in times is only due to memory/disk/cpu caches. Nothing more...

Answer (score 0):

Git 2.13 illustrates a bit more what is going on with a git checkout, through this optimization it proposes:
See [commit b986df5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b986df5c35a930858c6bba5f66c18ce6760d84e9), [commit 06b6d81](https://github.com/git/git/commit/06b6d81b7929ce6f5542ba869e7bb9d8e437e6f8), [commit e549463](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e5494631ed94017da862d55eb6393a0d01d8b91d), [commit 350d870](https://github.com/git/git/commit/350d8701437f2d5031513bb45f1d14545d5a8911) (19 Apr 2017), and [commit a6db3fb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a6db3fbb6e4ec11695e2a3af8bc2cb9119cb1941) (14 Apr 2017) by [Jeff Hostetler (`jeffhostetler`)](https://github.com/jeffhostetler).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 6cbc478](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6cbc478d83b5773d1925869e50bf6067306f4817), 26 Apr 2017)</sup>

It teaches `has_dir_name()` and `add_index_entry_with_check()` to see if the path of the new item is greater than the last path in the index array before attempting to search for it.

Adding:

> During checkout, `merge_working_tree()` populates the new index in sorted order, so this change will save a binary lookups per file.
>
> `has_dir_name()` is looking for file/directory collisions in the index and has to consider each sub-directory prefix in turn.
> This can cause multiple binary searches for each path.

See the gains for large repos in [commit b986df5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b986df5c35a930858c6bba5f66c18ce6760d84e9).